# Selecting image source on the fly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, callback, drawimage

I am trying to get the different source of image based on the array of objects.

If a person is male, it should display  men.png.

If a person is female, it should display  female.png.

The problem is I am getting only the female.png in the canvas.

Another problem is my callback function is not called on the order of the loop variable.

Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<canvas id ="canvas3" width="1100" height="100" ></canvas>
</div>
<script>


var person = [{name:" Mr.Ram T",gender:"Male"}, {name:" Dr.Shila G", gender:"Female"}, {name: " Dr. J Phil", gender:"Male" } , {name:" Mrs. Sita W",gender:"Female"}, {name:" Mrs. Gita W",gender:"Female"}, {name:" Mrs. Rita W",gender:"Female"}];

        function myCallBack(ilocal)
        {
            return function() 
                {   alert(ilocal);
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 10+ilocal*180, 5, 20, 20);
                };
        }


        for (i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas3');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var img = new Image();

            if( person[i].gender == "Male")
            {
                img.src = "men.png";
            }
            else
            {
                img.src = "female.png";
            }
            if ( img.complete ) 
            {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 10+i*180, 5, 20, 20);
            }
            else 
            {
            img.onload = myCallBack(i);
            }

        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A link to jsfiddle will be great mate.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The better alternative is to preload both your images before your app starts ...*

**Here's how to fully load both of your images before you try to draw them:**

1. Put your images urls in an array.
2. Loop through the urls array and create a new image object for each url.
3. Set each image objects `src` from the urls array.
4. Set each image's `onload` callback to a common function (f.ex: `myCallback`)
5. Add each image object to an images array.
6. The callback function will be called for each image in the images array, so count the number of times the callback function has been called. When its been called as many times as you have image objects you know you have fully loaded all the images.
7. With all images fully loaded ... use them in your code!

[image]

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var urls=[
  'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sillouette1.png',
  'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/sillouetteWoman.png'
];
var images=[];
var loadedCount=urls.length;
for(var i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
  var image=new Image();
  image.onload=myCallback;
  image.src=urls[i];
  images.push(image);
}
function myCallback(){
  // wait until all images have been fully loaded
  if(--loadedCount>0){return;}
  // Now all images have been loaded into images[] array
  // They are in the same order as the urls[] array
  var person = [
    {name:" Mr.Ram T",gender:"Male"}, 
    {name:" Dr.Shila G", gender:"Female"}, 
    {name: " Dr. J Phil", gender:"Male" } , 
    {name:" Mrs. Sita W",gender:"Female"}, 
    {name:" Mrs. Gita W",gender:"Female"}, 
    {name:" Mrs. Rita W",gender:"Female"}
  ];
  var x=0;
  for(var i=0;i<person.length;i++){
    var p=person[i];
    var genderIndex=(p.gender=='Male')?0:1;
    ctx.drawImage(images[genderIndex],x,0);
    ctx.fillText(p.name,x,125);
    x+=images[genderIndex].width;
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=600 height=150></canvas>
```